# Host domain from subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo

I use my htaccess to host my website from a subfolder like this:

```
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?su-mad.dk$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /version4/$1 [L]
```

My problem is that the same page can be reach two ways now,  with version4 and without. How can I stop this? Should I make a 301 redirect for the version4? (The version4 pages haven't been indexed by Google yet)

Answer (score 0):

> Should I make a 301 redirect for the version4?

Yes, but you need to match against the actual request instead of the internally passed around URI (which would cause a rewrite loop).

You can do it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+version4/([^\?\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```